# MySQL: Syntax error while linking two tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables: userdata and videodata. I have the email as the primary key in the first table (userdata) and I want to use email in the second table (videodata) as a foreign key.

userdata table-

[image: ss of userdata table]

Whenever I execute the query for the videodata table creation, I get this error-

[image]

Here is the query for creating videodata table-

[image]

Comment:  Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of code or data or errors. Copy the *text* into the question.

Comment: like is a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L

Comment: enclose like in back ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE is a reserved word. Enclose it in back ticks.

```
create videDate (
...
`like` int,
...
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A sillly mistake on my part lol